# What is the difference between FROM random IMPORT* and IMPORT random? (random() and randrange())

Tags: python, import

In the book has been this codesample:

```
from random import*
for i in range(15):                     
        print random.randrange(3,13,3)
```

And it have got result in the book.

But when I run it in the Netbeans. The following excaption arosed:

*

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Lacces\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Python_GS_Tanuljunk_meg_programozni\src\Adatszerkezetek\Lista.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       print random.randrange(3,13,3)  #3-tól 13-ig, 3 érték elválasztásal AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has
>   no attribute 'randrange'

*

I have call to help the google, and I found this for the import:

```
import random
```

With that I used this instead of *from random import**

And it worked! No exception!

Can somebody explain to me why throw exception at the first time, and why not at the second time (for a beginner programmer:))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you `from random import *`, all the definitions from `random` become part of the current name space. This means you don't have to prefix anything with `random.`, but it also means you may get a name collision without even knowing it.

The preferred way is `import random`.

Answer (score 3):

Importing everything from a module is discouraged just because of these surprising side effects: The module `random` contains a *function* random, so `import * from random` does the following:

```
from random import randrange
from random import random
...
```

Now, when you're accessing `random`, you're accessing the *function* instead of the *module*. You could use `randrange` (without the prefix `random.`), but `import random` and explicitly stating what module a function is from is the better idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you use 'from moduleName import ....' then you get all classes, functions and variables that you specified after import or all if you specify *.:
    from random import *
    for i in range(15):
        print randrange(3,13,3)

But note that this is not very good to import all, it would be better to import only required classes, functions and variables so in case you need only randrange you need to use:

```
from random import randrange
for i in range(15):                     
    print randrange(3,13,3)
```

In case you are using import random this means that you importing module so you need to specify moduleName. when you want to use it so:

```
import random
for i in range(15):                     
    print random.randrange(3,13,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

`from random import *` imports all functions from a module called random, but not `random` itself.

Here you can directly call the functions in random as follows: `randrange(3,13,3)`, etc

`import random` imports the name random, from which you can later call functions as follows: `random.randrange(3,13,3)`, etc